# Delete all rows in a HTML table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I have a HTML table in my MVC View.

Here is the code of this table:

```
<table class="table" >
    @{int rowNo = 0;}
    <tr>
        <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newAppointment" style="height: 40px; width: 40px; background: red;">
            <img style="object-fit: cover;" src='@Url.Content("~/Images/plus.png")'/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background: white">
        <th></th>
        <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;color:#1d69b4;">
            Date of birth
        </th>
        <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;color:#1d69b4;">
            Last Name
        </th>
        <th style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;color:#1d69b4;">
            First Name
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr id="patients">
            <td class="point">
                @(rowNo += 1)
            </td>
            <td class="title">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date_of_Birthday)
            </td>
            <td class="title">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Last_name)
            </td>
            <td class="title">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.First_name)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I need to delete all the rows in the table, so I need to delete everything in `patients`.

I tried to do it like the following via JS, but it only deletes the first row:

```
<script>
    $('#search').click(function () {
        $("#patients").remove();
    });
</script>
```

How can I delete all the rows?

Comment: The element with `id=patients` is a `<tr>` element and its invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes. Add a `<thead>` and `<tbody>` element with an `id` attribute and remove the `<tr>` elements from the `<tbody>` using `.empty()`

Comment: Thank's , it helps@StephenMuecke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An id is used to identify a unique element in the DOM. You're incorrectly generating multiple elements with the same id within your `foreach` loop. You might consider changing from `id` to `class`. Which allows the identification of multiple elements of the same type:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr class="patients">
        <!-- your code goes here -->
    </tr>
}
```

Then the appropriate selector removes all rows:

```
$('#search').click(function () {
   $(".patients").remove();
});
```